# Discount on total including shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, discount

I have a flat shipping rate set up i.e. if cart total less than Rs.800 then shipping is Rs.100, if more than Rs.800 then shipping is free.

I want to apply a flat 10% discount on the final total including shipping if any.

how would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### When you say final total it sounds like final grand total, not just shipping. If this is the case then suggest you use a Shopping Cart promotion rule to do this, you can select for the discount to also apply to the shipping amount.